# Arch Linux PHP 8 Do Not Upgrade

Tags: arch-linux, php

I understand how to ignore packages in pacman by editing the pacman.conf and addeding packages to the ignore list. My question is what packages do I need to include?

I use Apache and mod-PHP on my webserver running WordPress. I don't trust that WordPress and all my plugins will be updated to PHP 8 anytime soon. So I would like to continue to update my websever with the exception of PHP.

Can I ignore php*? Can wildcards be used? Do I need to specify each package? so PHP, php-gd, etc.

Do you know which packages I absolutely must include for php to not upgrade yet continue to work?

I feel that I need to do more than just not update php specifically.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[from documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Downgrading_packages)

(case-1):
Add package name to `IgnorePkg` line of `/etc/pacman.conf` file.

```
IgnorePkg = package1 package2
```

It will forbid `pacman --sysupgrade` install updates for the selected packages.

(case-2):
Change or #comment the addresses of the mirror-list repositories in which `pacman` searches for programs in:

```
nano /etc/pacman.conf
```